# ¿Se puede sobrecargar el operador [] en c++ para un tipo struct?

Tags: c++, operador

Estoy intentando sobrecargar el operador `[]` en c++ pero sin usar POO. He visto que hay preguntas similares pero en las que se usan clases y yo prefiero no usarlas.

Esto seria un ejemplo del codigo que querría hacer pero me da error en el compilador:

```
typedef struct listaNoCompleta {
    int cont;
    int array[22];
};

int operator[](listaNoCompleta lista, int indice)
{
    return lista.array[indice];
}
```

El error que me da es este `'operator[]' debe ser una función miembro`. Sinembargo con otros operadores si que me deja el unico que no es el `[]`. Ejemplo:

```
typedef struct listaNoCompleta {
    int cont;
    int array[22];
};

int operator+(listaNoCompleta l1, listaNoCompleta l2)
{
    return l1.array[0] + l2.array[0];
}
```

Este último codigo con el operador `+` ya no da error. No entiendo la diferencia entre esos dos operadores.

¿Existe alguna manera aunque no sea recomendable de conseguir sobrecargar el operador `[]` para el tipo `listaNoCompleta` o similares sin meter de por medio clases ni POO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la documentación, la sobrecarga del [operador `[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) solo puede estar dentro de la clase (o struct, ya que en C++ son lo mismo a excepción de la visibilidad por defecto) y debe tener la forma:

```
R& T::operator[](S b);
```

Una posible implementación es la siguiente:

```
struct listaNoCompleta {
    int cont;
    int array[22];

    int& operator[](int i){
        return array[i];
    }
};
```

[Aquí](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv@YoFwdaDUntsqz9ScwjbIAsxKdvNQaTfHlNSndPO8mYG5/n8REzpQB5dnCwMFBZha153pfIRUcDRIgY@CrLIC2Dw0v@dYTbvsW11r36/I4TZspHAo643hk4lvYmtRPZ7jHQpWtWa4xv6MuTrHS/DriBubDTc4NoUu8jUdRiiwDCAu5S6TGRXPXzVqzWlLw) puedes verlo en funcionamiento.

---

También es válido devolver una copia del valor (`int` en este caso) pero no podrás aprovechar el operador para cambiar el elemento almacenado en esa posición del arreglo.

---

Por cierto, en C++ no es necesario escribir `struct` cuando declaras una variable, contrario a lo que ocurre en C.

Por lo tanto el `typedef` es innecesario a menos que quieras crear un alias.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad llevaba todo el dia buscando informacion y sin conseguirlo

Comment: Como apunte adicional, en C++23 se ha cambiado el operador de indizado (`operator[]`) para poder recibir [múltiples parámetros](https://wg21.link/P2128R6) (ejemplo: `a[1,2,3]`) y para poder ser [estático](https://wg21.link/P2589R0).